# Editing a known HTML element and adding an attribute in C#

Tags: c#, browser

I want to figure out how I would do this:

HTML:

```
<input type="password" id="j_password" name="j_password" autocomplete="on">
```

How would I make my webBrowser1 add `value="testpass"` in the element, so after the execution that document would have:

```
<input type="password" id="j_password" name="j_password" autocomplete="on" value="testpass">
```

Comment: How is this a C# question?

Comment: Use jquery to add value to that element http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: not so descriptive question

Comment: @DigitalD <quote>How would I make my `webBrowser1`</quote>..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I already know this, but when I invoke the click after doing so, it doesn't sign in properly, which leaves me to believe the SetAttribute isn't working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SetAttribute` method:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;

void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("j_password").SetAttribute("value", "testpass");
}
```